# Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.security.jps.runtime.AppSecurityContext not found by SampleAuthPlugin [1]

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic, classpath

Background: I am trying to add some code to a custom Oracle OAM plugin.  The new code I am adding is to try to access what Oracle calls the "Identity Context".  I got some test code example from https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E27559_01/admin.1112/e27239/id_context.htm#AIAAG7296, but had to include two additional jars IdentityContext.jar and jps-api.jar (for AppSecurityContext) and I put those files into the WebLogic Domain/lib directory on my managed servers then bounced the managed servers.

After that, I am still get a ClassNotFoundException but it looks lie a little different than I am used to:

```
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.security.jps.runtime.AppSecurityContext not found by SampleAuthPlugin [1]
```

So I don't understand the error since the two JARs I added have the AppSecurityContext class and the associated inner class classes, so I'm assuming that the "different" exception is telling me something (BTW, SampleAuthPlugin is my custom plugin, which has the code to access the Identity context).

I am kind of guessing that something (maybe the Oracle OAM plugin infrastructure ) is not using the normal WebLogic classpath, and so even though I put the JARs into the DOMAIN/lib, the SampleAuthPlugin is causing something to look for the AppSecurityContext class in a JAR in some different directory??

Thanks,
Jim

EDIT: Here a more extensive stacktrace - it looks like the SampleAuthPlugin IS using it's own (or a different/special) classloader)?

```
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.security.jps.runtime.AppSecurityContext not found by SampleAuthPlugin [1]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1550)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:77)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1988)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sample.SampleAuthPlugin$1.run(SampleAuthPlugin.java:606)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sample.SampleAuthPlugin.getIDContext(SampleAuthPlugin.java:605)
    at sample.SampleAuthPlugin.ListContext(SampleAuthPlugin.java:584)
    at sample.SampleAuthPlugin.process(SampleAuthPlugin.java:406)
```

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3776254 might help

Comment: I think that you (or the linked thread) were suggesting putting a copy of the jps-ee.jar into the DOMAIN/lib dir?  I tried that and bounce both managed servers and got the same error.  Also here's a more extensive stacktrace - it seems like the SampleAuthPlugin is using it's own classloader?

Answer (score 0):

At least for my situation, the following worked:

1. In my plugin JAR, I added the following in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF:

Bundle-Classpath: .,jps-ee.jar, etc.

2. Then, I put the jps-ee.jar into the root of the plugin jar.

FYI, I built my plugin jar using Netbeans and for the 2nd step, I put the jps-ee.jar under the  in the Netbeans project.